# Remote Seam Persistence

Tags: seam, transactions, entitymanager, persist

I have a button in a .xhtml file which calls a javascript function which calls a java function remotely (in jboss seam environment). That java function has an entityManager.persist(object). Do you know why this line of code doesn't commit to the DB?
It says something that a transaction hasn't started. I supose in a remote context i don't have a transaction began because if i put an action on that button which calls the same java function instead of using javascript is above, it works fine; entityManager persists the object and i can see it in the DB.

Does anyone has any ideas how could i make to actually persist the object using javascript to call the java function? (i have to use javascript because i need the callback function )

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of your code? Its a bit hard to diagnose based on your text alone.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure a transaction You could extend org.jboss.seam.util.Work:

```
new Work()
{
    @Override
    protected Object work() throws Exception {
        // do your stuff
        return null;  
    }
}.workInTransaction()
```